# MariaDB SELECT query not returning correct results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an issue returning results from a table on the MariaDB slave to my MySQL DB, when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE colZ = 'GM' AND hour(colTime) = 18 AND colDate = 20170306;
```

I get a result showing 10 rows that match the criteria,

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEqtv.jpg)

yet when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE colZ IN ('GM','NS') AND hour(colTime) = 18 AND colDate = 20170306;
```

I get a result with 17 rows containing `GM` in `colZ` and then whatever matching `Y` values are expected (if any).

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpgOu.jpg)

So the question is: why are those 7 records not returning in the initial query? I have tried changing the first query to `colZ IN ('GM')` and the second query to `colZ = 'GM' or colZ = 'NS'` and both still return the same results.

There is no perceivable difference in the 7 additional rows that show up in the second query compared to those in the first.

Even weirder, when I run the same queries on the master mySQL DB, both return the 17 rows as expected.

Comment: Date as integer?!? Scary.

Comment: Show us sample table data, the current result and the expected result - all as well formatted text,.

Comment: @jarlh I have updated the question to include images, note that the PK values are definitely unique and correct, I have simply removed them and changed the column names. The date is in date format in the table

Comment: @jarlh it's not always scary, if you run a dwh that's normal... however you have to know what you are doing and why, otherwise yes it's scary ;)

Comment: how many rows are returned with just `colZ IN ('NS') and ...` ... 7?

Comment: @fthiella 0 rows returned with just NS, but I was not expecting any for that identifier and those criteria, I can use ANY second value in the IN to return the 17 results where colZ is GM

Comment: okay i undestrand the problem... which datatype is colZ ?

Comment: @fthiella char(2)

Comment: can you try to run `select colZ, hex(colZ) from t WHERE colZ IN ('GM','NS') and ...` .. are all vaules returned by hex the same?

Comment: @fthiella it returns the same hex for all 17 rows

Comment: i don't know how to help you, it looks weird... if you have the solution please post it

Comment: @CitizenFury ,  Please paste the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE t;`  `SHOW INDEX IN t;`  `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM t WHERE colZ = 'GM' AND hour(colTime) = 18 AND colDate = 20170306;` `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM t WHERE colZ IN ('GM','NS') AND hour(colTime) = 18 AND colDate = 20170306;`

Comment: Which Engine are you using?